# Invoking AAR library service through AIDL throwing Unable to start service intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice, aar

I included an aar library in my android application. And whatever activities, services, receivers are there in the library manifest file, I copied it to the Application manifest file.

Now I want to invoke the service of library through AIDL. When I'm starting the service, getting the issue "Unable to start service Intent"

Could some one help what extra I have to do to make it work?
How does the OS tells the service is available in the library?

Aar file library package name is "com.abc.lib".
The service in aar manifest file:

```
    <service android:name="com.abc.lib.MyService"
       android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.abc.lib.aidl.IMyService"/>
       </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Calling the above service from Application Activity file with the below code:

```
ComponentName compName = null;
Intent i = new Intent("com.abc.lib.aidl.IMyService");
i.setPackage("com.abc.lib");
compName = startService(i);
return compName;
```

Advance thanks.

Comment: add the service intent in library

Comment: I have added the service intent in library. And also the starting intent is very simple command

Comment: These are the commands                                                
                                                                                         
ComponentName compName = null;
Intent i = new Intent(com.abc.xyz.aidl.IMyService);
i.setPackage(com.abc.xyz);
i.putExtra("packagename", info.packageName);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
String pkg = "com.abc.xyz";
String cls = "com.abc.xyz.aidl.IMyService";
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
compName = startService(i);
return compName;

Comment: I read from android O onwards, component also me mentioned along with package. That'w why added it. And it is compiling well but not getting invoked

Comment: That is the service intent-filter which is mentioned in my aar library manifest file

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: I didn't copy paste the exact code. Bcoz i can't write the original package names. Its confidential

Comment: pskink.. I'm able to compile and install the apk.

Comment: It is working now. Posting the modified code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of library package in the intent.setPackage, I tried application package, it worked.

```
ComponentName compName = null;
Intent i = new Intent("com.abc.lib.aidl.IMyService");
i.setPackage("com.abc.application");  //Instead of library package-give the application package
compName = startService(i);
return compName;
```